PyCharm creates new thread when I attach debugger to running process
About three months ago I wrote a set of steps to attach the PDB debugger to a running process in Python (in Ubuntu 20.04).  These instructions worked well, but I haven't used them in about three weeks.  Today I tried this again, and instead it created a new thread, and I can't debug.
These are the instructions I wrote three months ago:


Put a line at the point where you want to start debugging:
input("Press Enter to continue...")


and put a breakpoint right below that line.

On Ubuntu 20.04, start by isssuing the command "echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope" as the article says.

Start the program in the PyCharm terminal (Alt-F12).

At the command prompt, enter "python3 Trans_01.py"

When it hits the breakpoint with "Press Enter to continue..." DO NOT PRESS ENTER.  Instead, attach the debugger with "Run" then "Attach to Process."  Now the debugger is attached, but the terminal now shows "Connected" but the prompt to press Enter to continue is gone.

Press Alt-F12 again and the terminal reappears.  Press Enter to continue, and it stops at my first breakpoint.


See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/attach-to-process.html

Today when I followed those steps, I was presented with these three options, and I chose to attach to 4947 Trans_01.py
-- 901 Python3; [New Thread 0x7fa26ffbc700 (LWP 15725)]
usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
-- 1075 usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
-- 4947 Trans_01.py
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
/usr/bin/python3.8 /snap/pycharm-community/439/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py --port 39251 --pid 4947
PYDEVD_GDB_SCAN_SHARED_LIBRARIES not set (scanning all libraries for needed symbols).
Running: gdb --nw --nh --nx --pid 4947 --batch --eval-command='set scheduler-locking off' --eval-command='set architecture auto' --eval-command='call (void*)dlopen("/snap/pycharm-community/439/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_linux_amd64.so", 2)' --eval-command='sharedlibrary attach_linux_amd64' --eval-command='call (int)DoAttach(0, "import sys;sys.path.append("/snap/pycharm-community/439/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev");sys.path.append("/snap/pycharm-community/439/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process");import attach_script;attach_script.attach(port=39251, host="127.0.0.1", protocol="", debug_mode="");", 0)'
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f836e5451f2 in __GI___libc_read (fd=0, buf=0xe349680, nbytes=1024) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:26
The target architecture is set automatically (currently i386:x86-64)
26  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c: No such file or directory.
$1 = (void *) 0xe2cb080
[Detaching after fork from child process 4966]
[New Thread 0x7f8369af0700 (LWP 4967)]
[New Thread 0x7f83692ef700 (LWP 4968)]
But when I return to the PyCharm debug window, I am not able to debug.  F7, F8 and F9 do not work at all.  This is not how it worked before, and I don't know why.
How can I attach the debugger to the running process and debug?  It appears to be assigned to a new thread, unlike several months ago.  Can I switch to that thread, and how?
Thanks very much for any help.
